# Is it possible to only have one file instead of a whole folder?

Tags: c#

Instead of having a folder for each project in C#, and many files, is it possible to just have one file for each project?
I am making console application (.NET Core), and it is annoying to have about 8 files when I am syncing across two computers, and it would be easier to just have a single file, per project.
I am used to Python where one file is enough, and that's nice. A whole folder filled with files that are almost the same each time is just annoying to me.
I am using VS Community 2019 if that matters.

Edit: I formulated myself in a very bad way, which meant I didn't get the answer I was looking for.

Comment: While this is may be a legitimate question, it feels like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) too. Sync code between computers is a problem already solved by version control systems, even for thousands of files. Besides, except for very small programs, having everything in a single file will lead to a lot of clutter of classes and methods.

Comment: If this happens to be for a Web API project, then try doing a search for `.NET 6 minimal api`. It is still in preview but very complete already.

Comment: Read about source control

Comment: What crappy sync program are you using that insists on picking file-by-agonizing-file for sync? Use one that can sync a folder.

Comment: But plus one for git instead of sync - being able to go back to any previous versions of a file and also compare changes since then will quickly prove itself indispensable

Answer (score 1):

There's absolutely nothing preventing you from having multiple classes in a single file.

```cs
namespace Hello
{
    public Class A
    {
    }

    public Class B
    {
    }
}
```